# Emacs how to hide globally the mode line

Tags: mode-line, format

I try to find a way to hide or disable globally the kind of status bar displayed below each window (called mode line).  I use [hide-mode-line](https://github.com/hlissner/emacs-hide-mode-line) package to hide the mode line in some major modes like `prog-mode` or `text-mode`, but it is still displayed in some places like dashboard, or while I list opened buffers.

[image: mode line hidden]
[image: mode line displayed]

Comment: I find this post which do the trick > https://bzg.fr/en/emacs-hide-mode-line/ The relevant comment is as follows: ```
;; If you want to hide the mode-line in every buffer by default
;; (add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'hidden-mode-line-mode)
```